# Different environments or the same environment updated in Poetry

Tags: python, git, python-poetry

**Background**

I am just starting to use Poetry.

I have a repository where I already did

```
poetry install --no-root
```

When I go to the folder with my code and I do this I get

```
$ poetry env list
MyProject-39jruye-py3.9 (Activated)
```

So all I need is to do `poetry shell` and I can proceed.

**What I need**

I have two scenarios that I want to accomplish. Please consider them separately.

1. First I want to add one dependency.

I suppose that I should just do `poetry add <new_library>` but that is it, right? No need to install again since add install it right? Does it matter if I do it inside the poetry shell or outside?

2. The previous one seemed easy. What happens if I have my `pyproject.toml` and my `poetry.lock` ready and I am in the main git branch, and I want to do an experiment that does not affect the main branch?

I suppose I will create a new branch `git checkout -b MyLittleExperiment` and inside that branch do the `poetry add <new_library>`.

My question is, what happens there?

- Will the environment have the new library in the feature branch and won't in the main branch automatically?
- Do I need to do anything other than checkout branches to get these?
- Are they the same environment? or am I creating different environments? and If they are the same, should I create a new environment for the experiment? How?